# Trying to populate php dropdown with data from sql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to populate a dropdown with a list of names from an mysql table. The table has columns for Name, Date, Host, and Info. I have looked around online, but I can't seem to find a solution to my issue. I am pretty sure it connects to the database, but I keep getting the error Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmsql\delegates.php on line 16.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'munapp');

if($db->connect_errno) { 
    die('Sorry we having some connection problems');
} 

$query = "SELECT Name FROM `conferences`";

$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query);

$options = "";

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $options = $options."<option>$row2[1]</option>";
}



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title> </title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>

    <body>


        <select>
            <?php echo $options;?>
        </select>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please update your table schema into your question. Or you can try with `mysqli_fetch_row()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$options` assignment to populate from `0` index in array:

```
$options = $options."<option>$row2[0]</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You wore trying to access the second column from the result, but you only selected one column.

Instead of the query:

```
$query = "SELECT Name FROM `conferences`";
```

select all columns like this:

```
$query = "SELECT name, date, host, info FROM `conferences`";
```

Answer (score 0):

Like someone else pointed out, you need to access the first array element with  an index of 0 instead of 1. Alternatively you could fetch your row like this:

```
while(row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  //accesss value here
}
```

which will give you the result as an associative array and then inside the loop access the values by their column namens like this:

```
$row2['Name']
```